# jquery checks randomly the checkbox

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

What's wrong here with this checkbox controller?
Jquery change the attribute in html but not the graphic checkbox...

html

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked"/>
<input type="checkbox"/>
<a href="#" class="no">off</a>
<a href="#" class="yes">on</a>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.yes').click(function(){
    $('input:checkbox').attr('checked','checked');
});
 $('.no').click(function(){
     $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
});
})
```

the test

http://jsfiddle.net/ehijon/Jmn3r/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change to use prop:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked',true); // --Change to false to uncheck
```

See fiddle update: http://jsfiddle.net/Jmn3r/1/